# How can I find all *old* Keynote presentations on my computer?

Tags: spotlight, keynote

I have some old Keynote presentations. When I try to open them with the latest Keynote (6.5.2 (2119)), I get the following warning:

```
This presentation can’t be opened because it’s too old.
To open it, save it with Keynote ’09 first.
```

I've managed to get `Keynote '09` installed, and I can open with that, save, open with the current version, and save again.

It will be a pain to do this with all of my Keynote presentations, but it seems it has to be done if I want to be able to access them in the future. Or I should convert them to PDF so they are in a format with more long-term access options.

How do I find all of the Keynote presentations on my computer that are outdated? Is there an `mdfind` option that will allow me to find just the old versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Smart Folder is probably the easiest way to find all your old Keynote files. To create one:

1. Open a Finder Window
2. Click "File" > "New Smart Folder"
3. In the search box, type "key" and then select "Keynote Document" from the dropdown
4. If you like, you can add a last modified filer by clicking the "+" sign under the search box.
5. If you want to save the Smart folder, click the "Save" button

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this list *all* Keynote documents, old and new?

Comment: I was counting on the date filter to eliminate the new files. It sounds like the OP just installed the new Keynote app recently.

Comment: I've been using new Keynote for a while. Just recently realized I can't open old ones, and should update them. This isn't a complete solution, but this plus sorting by "date modified" should help me out.

Comment: Strangely when searching I see all Keynote docs, but after saving the search and selecting it in the sidebar, nothing shows up.

Comment: That is odd. I see the same thing on my end. The workaround that I found was to edit the Smart Folder to search for the kind of "Keynote" instead of "Keynote Document". You can do this by following the steps below:

1. Secondary click on the smart search in the finder left panel and click on "Show Search Criteria".
2. Replace "Keynote Document" with "Keynote" and Save

Comment: I'm just using the CLI: `mdfind 'kMDItemKind = "Keynote Presentation" && kMDItemContentModificationDate < $time.today(-1)'`